# What is the most reliable free online English dictionary?

Tags: american-english

Wordnet has the "paper bag" issue. What is the best all-in-one dictionary?( synonyms,antonyms, etymology)

Comment: What's the paper bag issue? I like [onelook.com](http://onelook.com) and [dict.org](http://dict.org) for their sophisticated search facilities and quick surveys of multiple online dictionaries for a given word, so I can pick out the one which suits my need best, and [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com) for etymologies. For more, see [this Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574).

Comment: This is going to be opinion-based  but recognized dictionaries with professional lexicographers are what you want to use, and these include Oxford, Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, Collins, and MacMillan. Farley's 'The free dictionary' lists definitions from more than one of these dictionaries. Last  you can access most these dictionaries by looking a word up in [One Look](http://www.onelook.com), where a search will provide multiple returns with links to the above. It can  also include links to many others  so don't be overwhelmed.

Comment: I personally prefer the Oxford dictionary, popularly called the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/english) (ODO) because it provides multiple example sentences for each word. Type your word in the open search field. It is also not bogged down with images and/or advertisements. I would try to stay away from "learners dictionaries" unless you are a very beginner. They are extremely oversimplified and streamlined usually giving fewer uses than regular dictionaries. I don't recommend Wiktionary.